# How to add new submenu in Magento customers Admin menu?

Tags: magento2, adminmenu

I'd like to add submenu in Customer admin menu. I have this code below to show my custom submenu of customer support.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::customers_support_information"
            title="Customer Information"
            translate="title"
            module="CsCustomerSupport"
            sortOrder="50"
            parent="Magento_Customer::customer"
            action="cscustomersupport/customer/index"
            resource="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::customers_support_information"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

[image]

But it's not showing up. Anything I can do with this?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: please check your module status. your module must be enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
   <menu>
         <add id="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::customers_support_information"
            title="Ced CsCustomer Support"
            translate="title"
            module="Ced_CsCustomerSupport"
            sortOrder="50"
            parent="Magento_Customer::customer"
            resource="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::customers_support_information" />

          <add id="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::menu"
           title="Customer Information"
           module="Ced_CsCustomerSupport"
           sortOrder="100"
           parent="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::customers_support_information"
           action="cscustomersupport/customer/index"
           resource="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::menu"/>

</menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you @msquare. It works, is there any reason why I cant add submenu directly without making the header to the customer existing menu ?

Comment: you can add this line         <add id="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::menu" title="Customer Information" translate="title" module="Ced_CsCustomerSupport" sortOrder="80" parent="Magento_Customer::customer" action="cscustomersupport/customer/index" resource="Ced_CsCustomerSupport::menu"/>   to add only menu without title

Comment: please check and update me.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clearance @Msquare. I'm sorry, I can't upvote yet since im new here.

Comment: please update me above menu is added or not  ?

Comment: Done @Msquare :)